# Configuration error within buidling a D snippet in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, d

I'm just gonna taste the D programming. So, installed DDT plugin (in eclipse) and as soon as building a simple piece of code, as below:

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    writeln("Hello World.");
}
```

The following error has just been raised:

```
'Building Workspace has encountered a problem.
Errors occurred during the build.

Details:
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'DUB Build' on project 'DTest'.
melnorme.utilbox.core.CommonException: Cannot run program "dub" (in directory "F:\Eclipse\DTest"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

EDIT:

After installation of DUB, here is the issue:

```
Failed to invoke the compiler dmd to determine the build platform: '"dmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.
```

Thanks

---

**Solution:**

The problem had, seemingly, stemmed from simultaneous installation of to two different versions of `DMD`. As I removed the older one, the issue was just vanished.

Comment: Do you have Dub installed?

Comment: I did that, and please find the edit for the new issue.

Comment: Did you install DMD?

Comment: @sigod: Of course, even the PATH is the thing it should be. But the error does still insist on existing!

Comment: Can you try to open `cmd` and type `dmd` or try to compile through that to see if the problem is persistent. Otherwise I'd say it's a bug in ddt/eclipse.

Comment: @Bauss: Thanks, buddy... Seemingly the problem was existence of two different `dmd` versions on my machine...